# React axios get parameter is undefined

Tags: reactjs, django, rest, axios

I want to get some data from an API with a parameter current user's username.

```
useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(currentUser[0]?.id.toString())
        if (currentUser) {
            console.log(currentUser[0]?.id.toString())
            axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_chat2/?user1=${currentUser[0]?.id.toString()}&user2=`).then(res=>{
                setUsers(res.data)
                console.log(res.data)
            })    
},[currentUser])
```

When I print `currentUser[0]?.id.toString()` I get user's id but when I send the request it is undefined. I tried doing it a string but it still is undefined. Also when instead of id I use the username it isn't undefined.

Answer (score 2):

If this `currentUser` is an asynchronous value, then try the following code:

```
useEffect(()=>{
        const {id} = currentUser?.[0] || {};
        if (id) {
            axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_chat2/?user1=${id}&user2=`).then(res=>{
                setUsers(res.data)
                console.log(res.data)
            })    
},[currentUser])
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Can you explain what const {id} = currentUser?.[0] || {}; does? –

Comment: This is just a syntactic structure using JavaScript. It is equivalent to the following writing:

let id = '';

if (currentUser.length > 0 &&  currentUser[0].id) {
  id = currentUser[0].id;
}

Answer (score 0):

Check the API endpoint and make sure that its correctly configured to accept the "user1" and then debug to verify the value of currentUser[0]?.id.toString() just before making the GET request to ensure it's correct.

your modified code I think this will work.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const firstUser = currentUser?.[0];
    
    if (firstUser) {
        axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_chat2/?user1=${firstUser.id}&user2=`)
            .then(res => {
                setUsers(res.data);
            });
    }
}, [currentUser]);
```

Comment: It accepts user1 but I can't understand why when I put the username (which is a string) it  works normally but when I use the id (which is also a string) it returns undefined.